# Connection timed-out to RDS instance from inside lamba_handler function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

This works instantaneous:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="postgres", user="postgres", password="...", 
                        host="...", port=5432)
cursor = conn.cursor()
print(cursor)
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    pass
```

**output:
<cursor object at 0x7f5e00aeea70; closed: 0>**

This gives me connection time out:

```
import boto3
import json
import psycopg2

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    secret_name = 'db_credentials_secret_v2'
    client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
    current_secret = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
    secret_string = current_secret['SecretString']
    secret_dict = json.loads(secret_string)

    psycopg2.connect(dbname=secret_dict["username"], user=secret_dict["username"], password=secret_dict["password"], host=secret_dict["host"], port=secret_dict["port"])
```

They are in the same VPC, subnet. Security groups are set. Time out was increased to 15 minutes but same result.

Comment: What does the first code snippet represent? Python script running on EC2? The symptoms suggest, despite your assertion, that the Lambda function and EC2 instance do not have the same Security Group and/or network configuration.

Comment: Python script that runs outside of lambda_handler function.  It runs on lambda service, not ec2. They are in the same security group

Comment: If you added log lines to see where the timeout occurs, it is probably timing out on the `get_secret_value()` call. A Lambda function running in a VPC will not have access to resources outside the VPC unless you setup VPC endpoints for those AWS services, or configure the Lambda in a subnet with a route to a NAT Gateway.

Comment: @Mark. First of all thanks for the reply, secondly i'm just at the beginning with AWS services. Thirdly i don't want the lambda  to access anything outside of the VPC. Lastly, it times out exactly on the last line. The secrets are retrieved fine.

Comment: AWS Secrets Manager exists outside of the VPC. Amazon does not deploy that service into your VPC, it runs outside of your VPC. If you want to use Secrets Manager, you have to give the Lambda function some way to access it from within the VPC. Without seeing the logs, and without added debug logs in your code, I find it doubtful the timeout is really occurring on the last line of code, but if so, more debug logs, to print out the connection settings, especially the hostname and port, would be needed.

Comment: Hmm...well CloudWatch doesn't say anything to me after checking it's logs other than the billing duration, execution time and all that. I have some custom inline Policy attached to lambda that looks something like this::

 "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
"secretsmanager:RotateSecret",
"secretsmanager:UpdateSecret",
"secretsmanager:DescribeSecret" with Resources: "*".  i have also AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole attached

Comment: Also if i remove the last line with the connection attempt, the secrets are retrieved, that's why i'm saying the time out happens on the last line

Comment: Actually it doesn't work, amazing. Need to check why, because it worked before.

Comment: @MarkB So, I did like you said. I've added a VPC endpoint for Secret Manager and in the same security group i've added 2 new rules. For inbound, using port 443 with the source of Lambda's subnet and for the outbound one, same port but the destination being the CIDR of my default VPC. I can't say it doesn't work as expected everything now, however i don't understand exactly why it does :). Especially why i need these 2 rules for outbound and inbound but i'll see to it eventually i guess. Anyway, thanks for the directions. Regards.

Comment: The logs in cloudwatch would only show what you print/log in your code. When I said you need to add logging, I meant you need to add some print or log statements to debug the problem.

Comment: Lambda would communicate with Secrets Manager over the default HTTPS port (port `443`). I can't really follow the rest of what you say about the security group, but that's why you would need a rule for that port. It sounds like you are using the same security group for multiple different things (the vpc endpoint, Lambda function, maybe RDS also) which is why the rules would be confusing. It would be cleaner and make more sene if you had a different security group for each of those.